# Include cpp file if condition fulfilled

Tags: c++, include, c-preprocessor

In my file C++ project I want to include files only if certain conditions are fulfilled.

The aimed code is something like

```
#if condition1
   #include file1.cpp
#endif
#if condition2
   #include file2.cpp
#endif
```

I do not really know how to solve this. #include is a preprocessor statement while the if conditions have to be calculated within the program. In the above code no file is loaded since neither condition is fulfilled. If I change to

```
if condition1{
   #include file1.cpp
...
```

all files get included since the preprocessor find the #include statements regardless of the if statement.

So far I have not found a third possibility.

Comment: What kind of condition would you like to test? The first code is valid as long as the condition can be established at compile-time. If you want to test run-time condition, you'll have to design your code in another way since it cannot be done with preprocessor.

Comment: #ifdef myFlag #include <test.hpp> #else #include <other.hpp> #endif should do the trick. Why would you like to include .cpp files?

Comment: I had the bad feeling that it cannot be done with preprocessor. The .cpp are data files. Depending on some results of the code the correct one should be loaded. The format is designed such that it can be included in the code very easily...

Comment: Broadly speaking, you can't make runtime decisions about what code to compile. What is the underlying problem that this is trying to solve?

Comment: Just as a [FYI] one should not include cpp files.  If you need different cpp files compiled based on different things then that is normally indicates you need to use a makefile to build the project.

Comment: I know that it is not good style in general to include cpp files. The data format is really nice if one knows what is the needed file. With just one line one can change include it. It seems to be not very nice if one wants to change it.

Answer (score 0):

The general answer is that you cannot do what you say you want to the way you want to do it. However, depending on what your goal is there might be ways to achieve it. (You also haven't mentioned which development environment you use.)

1) You could create different targets for the different versions that include the different cpp files. Most C++ environments have options to pass #define values in on the command line, so you can pass the target name in that way. Then you can use #if directives at compile time to test which target you are building.

2) You could compile and link the cpp files that vary as separate binaries and dynamically load them into your program at run time. I believe this is pretty easy in an environment like .NET with C# but perhaps a bit more work in a C++ project, again depending on your environment and what you are trying to do.